# INTEGER type in React native expo SQLite limited to 4 bytes?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native, expo, integer-overflow

When trying to insert a signed integer equal to 4 bytes - 1 bit (i.e. 2^31 i.e. 2147483648) I get an integer overflow condition (i.e. it is converted to -2147483648).

The sqlite docs state the INTEGER type supports up to 8 byte signed integer: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
Additionally values above 8 bytes - 1 bit - 1 cause an exception.  So this leads to the idea it's an expo / react-native bug.  Is this a known bug in Expo / react-native / something else?  I couldn't find [where `ExponentSQLite` is coming from](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/67f55e2b8b1e9801fe8cf0f67b114c9bc7d26b55/packages/expo/src/SQLite.ts#L7).  Note also that `2147483648` is well below the javascript MAX_SAFE_INTEGER so perhaps in the android code the parameters are being converted into a 4 byte signed integer.

```
import { SQLite } from 'expo'

async function main() {
  const db = SQLite.openDatabase('mydb')

  await exec_sql({ db, sql: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name;` })
  await exec_sql({ db, sql: `CREATE TABLE table_name (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, created_at INTEGER NOT NULL);` })
  await exec_sql({ db, sql: `INSERT INTO table_name (created_at) VALUES (?);`, parameters: [Math.pow(2, (8 * 4) - 1) - 1] })
  await exec_sql({ db, sql: `INSERT INTO table_name (created_at) VALUES (?);`, parameters: [Math.pow(2, (8 * 4) - 1)] })

  await exec_sql({ db, sql: `INSERT INTO table_name (created_at) VALUES (9223372036854775000);`, parameters: [] })
  // set to 9223372036854775000 as javascript Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER means `Math.pow(2, (8 * 8) - 1) - 1`
  // is rounded higher to 9223372036854776000
  await exec_sql({ db, sql: `INSERT INTO table_name (created_at) VALUES (?);`, parameters: [9223372036854775000] })

// This will error with
  // Error in callNativeModules()
  // Over flow during conversion: 9223372036854776000 (rounding up due to javascript's Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
  // await exec_sql({ db, sql: `INSERT INTO table_name (created_at) VALUES (?);`, parameters: [Math.pow(2, (8 * 8) - 1)] })
  await exec_sql({ db, sql: `SELECT * FROM table_name;` })
}

main()

function exec_sql ({ db, sql, parameters = [] }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction(tx => {
      console.debug(`Executing ${sql} with parameters: ${parameters}`)
      tx.executeSql(sql, parameters,
        (_, result) => {
          console.debug(`Have result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
          if (result && result.rows && result.rows._array) {
            resolve({ items: result.rows._array })
          } else {
            resolve()
          }
        },
        (_, err) => {
          console.error(`Error during executing sql: `, err)
          reject(err)
        }
      )
    })
  })
}
```

This will result in (edited for brevity):

```
Executing CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, created_at INTEGER NOT NULL); with parameters: 
Executing INSERT INTO table_name (created_at) VALUES (?); with parameters: 2147483647
Executing INSERT INTO table_name (created_at) VALUES (?); with parameters: 2147483648
Executing INSERT INTO table_name (created_at) VALUES (9223372036854775000); with parameters: 
Executing INSERT INTO table_name (created_at) VALUES (?); with parameters: 9223372036854775000
Executing SELECT * FROM table_name; with parameters: 
Have result: [{"id": 1, "created_at": 2147483647}, {"id": 2, "created_at": -2147483648}, {"id": 3, "created_at": -808},{"id": 4, "created_at": -1024}]
```

PRAGMA user_version -> 0
PRAGMA schema_version -> 46
expo version -> 31.0.2

*** Edit 1 ***

I have filed a bug, let's see what the response is: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3000

Comment: Maybe integer is stored as [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), then the first bit is the sign of the number and only 7 bits can be used for the range of the number.

Comment: I've opened a bug report here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug.
Has been fixed with: https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/3005